# open loading after dismiss in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I creating loadingController then show with present method.
then after second dismiss.
I want to use this loadingController without create again.
but not show loading dialog when use present method again.
how to use of loadingController after create and dismiss?

Comment: Why not to create again?

Comment: is not slow create? for performance